# Customizing product prices make cart items price showing 0

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, product

I am trying to change the price of the product based on location.

For this i am using wc fields factory to create number of fields for locations and updating the price and based on IP i am finding the city(location) and i am fetching the custom field value.

Using

```
function return_custom_price($price, $product) {
    global $post, $blog_id;
    $price = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_regular_price');
    $post_id = $post->ID;
    $price = ($price[0]*2.5);
    return $price;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_get_price', 'return_custom_price', 10, 2);
```

Its working fine, but when i go to view Cart there it showing product price as 0
like this:

[image: product price gettting zero]

Please help me out in this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Update:**

The product meta data **`'_regular_price'`** is not a custom field but the product regular price, that you can get directly [**using WC_Product methods and magic properties directly**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product.html#_get_regular_price) on the **`$product`** object.

> If you look to your function you have 2 arguments: **`$price`** (the product price) and the **`$product`** (the product object)… So you don't need to use any global variables as you got already $product object, that you can use.

Here is the updated code:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_get_price', 'product_custom_price', 10, 2);
function product_custom_price($price, $product) {
    $custom_price = $product->get_regular_price();
    return $custom_price * 2.5;
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

Please see the cart screenshots:

1) The cart without using this code (before):

[image: cart without using this code]

2) The cart using this the code (after):

[image]

> **As you can see, this code works perfectly and display the regular prices in cart items.**

---

The OP is using this code with a custom field:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_get_price', 'product_custom_price', 10, 2); 
function product_custom_price($price, $product) { 
    $custom_price = get_post_meta($product->id, 'custom_key', true); 
    return $custom_price; 
}
```

Comment: Hi,thanks for your reply but its not working for me

`add_filter('woocommerce_get_price', 'return_custom_price', 10, 2);
function return_custom_price($price, $product) {
global $post;
$price = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'wccaf_noida', true);
return $price;
}`

this is the way i am trying to fetch the value from custom field and its working fine in product page but its not updating in cart page. It shows 0.

Comment: and also some time i tried with cart hooks.

`function return_custom_price( $price_html, $product ) { global $post, $blog_id; $post_id = $post->ID; $noida_price = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'wccaf_noida', true); if ( ! empty( $noida_price ) ) { $price_html = wc_price( $noida_price ) ; } return $price_html; } add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'return_custom_price', 10, 2 );`

 this is my original price tag where i am fetching from custom field. but in cart its taking old regular price only. Its not helping me out.

Comment: @Lohith OK i didn't understand that as you dont explain it very well… so I am going to update my code… without using globals, that are not necessary… But `_regular_price` is not really a custom field as it's the regular product price that you can get by a WC_Product method…

Comment: thanks for the reply,  i am sorry for not giving clear info

let me clearly explain my requirement, I have to show different price for the product based on City location. So i have planned to get City by IP and city value using custom fields where i update my custom city locations values or prices. the code what i am trying its working perfect in product page but its not working in cart page. and the one you gave its working exactly what i wanted but i am not getting what is the mistake i am doing in my code. In cart page it shows either regular price or price of product as 0.

Comment: `add_filter('woocommerce_get_price', 'return_custom_price', 10, 2);
function return_custom_price($price, $product) {
 global $post;
 $nprice = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'wccaf_noida', true);

 if(!empty($nprice)){
  $price = $nprice;
 }

    return $price;
}`

Comment: and in the above code if i wont use `global $post;`  it wont fetch the custom field value i created. And the code you gave its just working fine as its simple edit with the price. but when i am trying to assign different value to the price its not accepting it. I am not getting where i am making mistake. Either it fetch its regular price or makes the product price as 0 in Cart page.

Comment: [link](http://gwfurniture.qodesoft.com/product/a608-d608-fff7147/)[/link] here is the error what i am facing. and i am using same your code just altered `add_filter('woocommerce_get_price', 'return_custom_price', 10, 2);
function return_custom_price($price, $product) {
    global $post;
    $nprice = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'wccaf_noida', true);
    $custom_price = $product->get_regular_price();
    return $nprice;
}
` but its making cart product price as 0.

Comment: `add_filter('woocommerce_get_price', 'return_custom_price', 10, 2);
function return_custom_price($price, $product) {
    global $post;
    
     $nprice = get_post_meta($product->id, 'wccaf_noida', true);
    $custom_price = $product->get_regular_price();
    return $nprice;
}` this solves the problem. $product->id should be used instead of $product->ID. sorry sometime small errors make more complex. thanks alot. Problem solved.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec hey best woocommerce expert on SO :), my mini cart showing old price which is set using filter `woocommerce_product_get_price`. however i have updated price using `woocommerce_before_calculate_totals` filter but my minicart get old price when `woocommerce_get_refreshed_fragments` ajax call

Comment: @LoicTheAztec :) thanks, sent you request from Nirmal Goswami